How to reference entity property in JPA JQL?
I have SQL table posts with properties
id
user_id
is_active

I have Java class PostsRepository:
public interface PostsRepository extends CrudRepository<PostEntity, Long> {
    Collection<PostEntity> findByUser(UserEntity user);
}

Now I want to modify findByUser method to return only posts where column is_active equal to true.
As I understand there is no "generic" template for methods which will generate my query just by method name findActiveByUser, so I need to use JPA @Query annotation;
public interface PostsRepository extends CrudRepository<PostEntity, Long> {
    
    @Query("SELECT p FROM PostEntity p WHERE p.is_active = true AND p.user.id = ?How to reference User ID?")
    Collection<PostEntity> findActiveByUser(UserEntity user);
}

The problem is I don't know how to reference user ID in this query. I can find examples of using method parameters of primitive types in JQL query, but I can't find examples of using entities properties in JQL query.

You need to add PostEntity to your question in order for anybody not familiar with your code to help.

You should use UserEntity as a param:
public interface PostsRepository extends CrudRepository<PostEntity, Long> {

 @Query("SELECT p FROM PostEntity p WHERE p.isActive = true AND p.user = :user")
 Collection<PostEntity> findActiveByUser(@Param("user") UserEntity user);

}

Or if you want to use userId you can change the method into :
@Query("SELECT p FROM PostEntity p WHERE p.isActive = true AND p.user.id = :id")
 Collection<PostEntity> findActiveByUserId(@Param("id") Long id);


Thanks. I needed to know that I can compare objects in JQL like this: p.user = :user
